# inverted index algorithm for AVL tree duplicates key each time c++

Tags: c++, avl-tree

i have created a inverted indexing algorithm to store indices in an AVL tree but every time i call the function it repopulates the tree with the new key and keys that are already in the tree.

here is the function

```
void IdeaBank::AVLTreeIndexing(){
    for (int loop = 0; loop < newIdea.size(); loop++) {
        vector<string> keywords = newIdea[loop].getKeyword();
        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i++) {
            Index input;
            input.key = keywords[i]; 
            for (int j = 0; j < newIdea.size(); j++) {
                if (newIdea[j].foundWordInBoth(keywords[i])) {
                    input.idList.push_back(newIdea[j].getID());
                    //removeDuplicates(input.idList);

                }
            } 
            tree.AVL_Insert(input);
        }
    }
}
```

the code above searches my idea bank for matches and pushes back the ID of the idea with a match to be stored in my avl tree.
I am calling this function every time i create a new idea however it stores the new key as well as all the previous keys.

this is what i have tried to do:
before inserting into the AVL tree i have a function to remove duplicates from my vector and then insert into my tree. however this did not solve the problem.

here is my function to remove duplicates

```
void removeDuplicates(vector<int> &v){
            auto end = v.end();
            for (auto it = v.begin();it !=end;it++){
                end = remove(it+1,end,*it);
            }
            v.erase(end,v.end());
        }
```

the code was copied from another stack overflow question that was marked as correct.

I am looking for a way to check if a key already exists in the tree and if it does to ignore it instead of repopulating the tree with duplicates.

EDIT: below is my code for my insert functions. I was thinking there might be a way to remove duplicates in there instead?

```
template <class TYPE>
struct NODE 
    {
     TYPE    data;
     NODE   *left;
     NODE   *right;
     int     bal;
     int     count;
    } ; // NODE

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool   AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE> :: AVL_Insert (TYPE dataIn) 
{
//  Local Definitions 
    NODE<TYPE>  *newPtr;
    bool         taller;

//  Statements 
    if (!(newPtr = new NODE<TYPE>))
       return false;
    newPtr->bal    = EH;
    newPtr->right  = NULL;
    newPtr->left   = NULL;
    newPtr->data   = dataIn;

    tree = _insert(tree, newPtr, taller);
    count++;
    return true;
}   //  Avl_Insert   

/*  ======================= _insert =======================
    This function uses recursion to insert the new data into 
    a leaf node in the AVL tree.
       Pre    application has called AVL_Insert, which passes 
              root and data pointers
       Post   data have been inserted
       Return pointer to [potentially] new root
*/

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
NODE<TYPE>*  AvlTree<TYPE,  KTYPE> 
         ::  _insert (NODE<TYPE>  *root, 
                      NODE<TYPE>  *newPtr, 
                      bool&        taller)
{
//  Statements   
    if (!root)
    {
        root    = newPtr;
        taller  = true;
        return  root;
    } //  if NULL tree 

    {
        return newPtr->data;
    }

    if (newPtr->data.key < root->data.key)
       {
        root->left = _insert(root->left, 
                             newPtr, 
                             taller);
        if (taller)
           //  Left subtree is taller 
           switch (root->bal)
              {
               case LH: // Was left high--rotate 
                        root = leftBalance (root, taller);
                        break;

               case EH: // Was balanced--now LH 
                        root->bal = LH;
                        break;

               case RH: // Was right high--now EH 
                        root->bal = EH;
                        taller    = false;
                        break;
              } // switch 
       } //  new < node 
    else 
       //  new data >= root data 
       {
        root->right = _insert (root->right, 
                               newPtr, 
                               taller);
        if (taller)
           // Right subtree is taller
           switch (root->bal)
               {
                case LH: // Was left high--now EH 
                         root->bal = EH;
                         taller    = false;
                         break;

                case EH: // Was balanced--now RH
                         root->bal = RH;
                         break;

                case RH: // Was right high--rotate 
                         root = rightBalance (root, taller);
                         break;
               } //  switch 
       } //  else new data >= root data 
    return root;
}   //  _insert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would add a condition to ensure that you are not comparing it to itself. So, just add:

```
if(loop != j)
```